# Why all of sudden Ubuntu 20.04 becomes slow, very slow? (It's been one month still no solution)

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu: 20.04.1 LTS
Intel i7 9th Gen
Graphics: Nvidia GeForce 1660 ti 6GB
256 SSD (Ubuntu Installed) 1TB HDD
I open my system, I usually do my work, sometimes, when only disconnect or connect to an Wi-Fi network, all of a sudden it works slow, very slow. Even the mouse response being delayed is very acknowledgeable. Doesn't know if Wi-Fi or anyother is responsible. Please is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image: top in terminal gives me this, when running only chrome currently and terminal opened,]

[image: And this is screnshot of free -h and vm.swappiness]

Comment: there must be something running in the background...Identify it using the System Monitor application..or type "top" in terminal

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and screenshots of the `top` command in `terminal`, and the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** scrollable data windows for both SSD and HDD.

Comment: any temperature related log entries in `/var/log/syslog` and/or `/var/log/kern.log` and/or `/var/log/*`? Just as a test, try running with turbo disabled or the maximum CPU frequency reduced.

Comment: @heynnema I did as you said. Did you find anything?

Comment: @DougSmythies What am I searching in `/var/log/*`. how to know what causing this?

Comment: You are looking for any temperature related log entries in any file, but if there are any they should be in the 2 files I specifically listed. However, I am not certain, so suggested to just look everywhere.

Comment: You didn't show me the SMART Data. vm.swappiness=1 is wrong. Set it to at least 10. That may have an effect on your problem. Keep watching `free -h` while you're working, and see how high the swap usage goes. Do you have any Chrome extensions/apps installed?

Comment: What's SMART Data? You mean disks? I don't meant any disrespect but, I don't any other softwares/applications. But for oral, I have 256GB SSD, in which 500MB EFI, 4GB swap partition and rest is root. I only installed chrome and no extentsions, apps, I only installed skype, timeshift, rest are defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command `sudo apt install htop` to install Htop to see what's causing the heavy load. If you find one, just simply kill the process to check if that solves your problem.

Comment: I don't usually have any third party applications installed, so how could they cause it. You think one of any software present in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS itself is making this happen? But I found out that, If I connect to Wi-Fi and use sometime and if connection interrupts or if I disconnect, then my pc was slow, after a reboot it came normal So, any thoughts?

Comment: do you have some network storage mounted or use VPN or so?

Comment: This information needs to be in your Question above, not buried among one answer's comments where few will see it.

Comment: @user535733 hey I am not sure that Wi-Fi is doing that or I am even sure now, so how can I say it in question then.